# Sinatra Error Handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra rest and I am having trouble trapping an error. I also admit I am fairly new to Ruby and Sinatra.

When I raise and error in the post endpoint I want to report the incoming document. I need to either 1) handle the error within the post result (where I have access to @incoming) or 2) pass the incoming document to the error and report it there.

What is a better option, option 1 or option 2?

- If I stay with option 1, how do I prevent error from picking up the error (as it seems to be doing now)
- If I go to option 2, how do I pass incoming to error?

Below is a sample of my code:

```
post ('/result') do 

  begin  
  @incoming = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

  //do something that causes an error
  rescue
     e = env['sinatra.error']
     url = request.url
     ip = request.ip

     @actlogpassblock = {  :message => e.message,
                        :path => url,
                        :ip => ip,
                        :timestamp => Time.new,
                        :type => "500",
                        :sub => "RES",
                        :payload => @incoming
                      }        
    action_log.insert(@actlogpassblock)
    status 500 
  end
end

error do
   status 500 
   e = env['sinatra.error']
   url = request.url
   ip = request.ip
   backtrace = "Application error\n#{e}\n#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"

  @actlogpassblock = {  :message => e.message,
                        :path => url,
                        :ip => ip,
                        :timestamp => Time.new,
                        :type => "500",
                        :backtrace => backtrace
                      }        
  action_log.insert(@actlogpassblock)
  {:result => 'Ah Shucks! Something went wrong'}.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> If I stay with option 1, how do I prevent error from picking up the
>   error (as it seems to be doing now)

According to the docs:

> The error handler is invoked any time an exception is raised from a
>   route block...

However, that only applies to *uncaught* exceptions.  Try this:

```
require 'sinatra'
set :show_exceptions, false

get '/' do
  begin
    raise ZeroDivisionError
  rescue ZeroDivisionError
    "rescue clause"
  end
end

error do
  "sinatra error handler" 
end
```

Then try this:

```
get '/' do
  raise ZeroDivisionError
end

error do
  "sinatra error handler" 
end
```

Also, you can tailor the error handler to only catch certain exceptions thereby avoiding some exceptions, e.g.

```
error IndexError do ...
```

or

```
error MyCustomException do ...
```

or

```
error 400..510 do
```

But for the catch all version:

```
error do
```

you can't stop that from executing when an uncaught exception occurs in a route block...unless:

> The error handlers will only be invoked, however, if both the Sinatra
>   **:raise_errors** and **:show_exceptions** configuration options have been set
>   to false...
>
> **:raise_errors** defaults to true in the "test" environment and to false
>   on other environments.
>
> **:show_exceptions** value defaults to true in the
>   "development" environment and to false on other environments
>
> The author of Sintra has said: "This [behavior] is 
>   intentional. The idea is that error blocks will hide the issue and you
>   usually don't want to do this in development mode.

https://github.com/sul-dlss/sdr-services-app/blob/master/Sinatra-error-handling.md

> If I go to option 2, how do I pass incoming to error?

An @variable that is created inside a route block can be seen inside an error block.  Try this:

```
require 'sinatra'
set :show_exceptions, false

get '/' do
  @incoming = "hello world"    #create @variable
  raise ZeroDivisionError
end

error ZeroDivisionError do
  @incoming                    #retrieve @variable
end
```

After entering the url `http://localhost:4567` in your browser, you should see "hello world" on the returned web page.

The reason that works is because an @variable attaches itself to whatever object is self at the time the @variable is created; likewise when an @variable is summoned, it is retrieved from whatever object is self at that time.  When Sinatra executes either the route block or the error block it sets self to the same object.

Option 2 seems nice because it separates the error handling code from the application code.

Comment: In my case the error block was never called, so i use the `set :show_exceptions, false` inside configure block and now all the RuntimeError are catched.

Comment: I have to set :raise_errors to true to get the server to handle it. It seems as though the documentation agrees with that as well. "Enabling the :raise_errors setting causes exceptions to be raised outside of the application where it may be handled by the server handler..."